# Mysql select query issue where id in ()

Tags: php, mysql

I have filters on my site.
where i have multiple checkbox to show products from different site.
if user select 2 checkboxes my query become

```
Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN (2,8);
```

its running fine.

But when user not select any checkboxes it becomes

```
Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN ();
```

and give error.I was thinking it should return empty results.

can any body help me i did not wanna remove this code where provider_id IN ();

so there must be a solution if any checkbox is not checked we handle this IN();

so need to know what i need to put in brackets if any checkbox is not checked.i.e IN ();

You people are genius.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use 0 as default IN argument, like `Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN (0);`. And when user selects any checkbox simply add their id-s.

Comment: Simply add a test in your PHP code and perform the query only if any checkbox is checked. Sending a SELECT query to the database when you do not expect any results is just bullshit.

Comment: no case is that if i will not add this where provider_id in() it will return all results because query will become.select * from new_deals.

Comment: Thanks Valdars i was looking for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do like this

```
$delim  =   "";
$whereCondition =   (count($_POST['multiple_check']) > 0) ? " where provider_id IN (" : "";

foreach ($_POST['multiple_check'] as $multipleCheckbox) {
     $whereCondition    .=  $delim.$multipleCheckbox;
     $delim =   ",";
}
$whereCondition .=  (count($_POST['multiple_check']) > 0) ? ")" : "where provider_id IN (NULL)";

if ($whereCondition != "") {
    $query  =   "Select * from new_deals {$whereCondition}";
}
```

Comment: OP didn't want to get the whole table as result. He expects an empty result

Comment: it will give all products which is not correct as user have not check any checkbox.

Comment: That is a horrible piece of code. Why don't you enclose everything in an if-clause that checks "count > 0" once (like raheel proposed)?

Comment: @Niko What is horror here??. Only thing is `$whereCondition` variable space is wasted in the memory!!!!! But still it is empty and deleted after execution.. Next time he come up with some other criteria, above code is well suitable. Example some search value to be added. We are giving OP to understand what are all the possibilities and how to code feasible in future. Think before you comment and vote. See @raheel shan is added good idea, already OP knows that. Why should I copy paste ?????

Answer (score 11):

You are using php so here is a solution:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkboxfieldname']) and count($_POST['checkboxfieldname']) > 0) {
     // run query
} else {
  // dont run query
}
```

Comment: this is excellent solution.Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN (0);Valdars youa re genius.becuase if i will not run query it means all records will show which is not correct.select * from new_deals where 1 and deal_id in (select deal_id from wp_deal_location_mapping where deal_location_id in (33)) and deal_category_id IN (2,5,6,7,1,3,4) and main_provider_id IN (0);

Comment: Well thanks!and welcome. conditions are for this purpose. Always play with conditions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, your problem is SQL is generating error if no checkboxes are selected.

Why don't you use

```
NULL
```

So that if there are no checkboxes selected, the code should be

```
Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN (NULL);
```

I have tried this and it does not give any error.

Thanks.

Comment: One big issue with this approach. If there exist one or more items which has `provider_id` = `null` this will fail.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I have executed this query: "SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE provider_id IN (NULL, NULL)". And it works. Please let me know in case you have any better suggestion.

Comment: yes it is also good answer.i was forget that.i was using IN (0).is that aslo fine.?

Comment: @AmolBhavsar If you set `provider_id` to `null` in database this query will retrieve that note and as far as I understood OP's question it is not expected behavior.

Comment: yes you are right.Because in my table this case never happen that a provider id have null value.so if user not select any checkbox we should pass null.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration!

Comment: @Leri `IN (NULL)` won't return anything, even `NULL`s. To match against `NULL` you need to use `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You could use WHERE provider_id IN(0) if 0 is an id you dont have in your DB. This is ugly as hell and you should instead just not run the query at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this methodology when you work with search.

Create a variable to contain addition conditions of SQL Query. In your case lets say your request variable is provider_id.

```
$QueryAddons = "";

if(isset($_REQUEST['provider_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['provider_id'])){
     $QueryAddons .= "AND provider_id IN ".implode(",",$_REQUEST['provider_id'])."";
}
```

Now your Query Statement Should Be :

```
  $selectStmt = "Select * from new_deals where 1=1 ".$QueryAddons;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to not even run the query if there aren't any IDs selected, but sometimes this isn't possible or results in more confusing code. So instead just add the value `NULL` to the list - `NULL` doesn't match anything (even other `NULL`s) so it's more suitable than using `0` or any other arbitrary value that could exist.

```
// IDs got from checkboxes
$ids = array("10", "12");

// Add in NULL
$ids[] = "NULL";

$values = implode(",", $ids);
$sql = "Select * from new_deals where provider_id IN ($values)";
```